# I have a variable with 7 sub variable. (E.g. 1 question has 7 answers)

Tags: spss, survey

So I did a cronbach test on all 7 answers and found that gave a result of 0.341. Unfortunately I understand we should not use this variable as it will be deemed as unacceptable, but for assignment-wise and based on the nature of the question, it is imperative to use this independent variable and find the correlation to the dependent variable.

I ran factor analysis for the 7 answers and got a 38.8% cumulative variance. Upon checking the extraction, I removed the variables below 0.3 hence online 6 and 5 was removed.

However, I was advised to do a summation of all variables instead of factor analysis. Can I know when this should be done and how do I confirm this is the required format?

````
online1 2.52    1.164   0.205   0.071   0.349
online2 2.58    0.998   0.333   0.167   0.269
online3 2.84    0.836   0.291   0.148   0.269
online4 3.17    0.927   0.238   0.064   0.312
online5 2.74    1.029   0.107   0.020   0.406
online6 3.41    1.265   0.070   0.006   0.395
online7 3.45    1.333   -0.077  0.012   0.431

**Factor Analysis**
Communalities
    Initial Extraction
online1 1.000   0.412
online2 1.000   0.543
online3 1.000   0.581
online4 1.000   0.342
online5 1.000   0.295
online6 1.000   0.051
online7 1.000   0.497
 
KMO and Bartlett's Test
Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin Measure of Sampling Adequacy.        0.630
Bartlett's Test of Sphericity   Approx. Chi-Square  431.463
    df  21
    Sig.    0.000
 
Correlation Matrixa
        online1 online2 online3 online4 online5 online6 online7
Correlation online1 1.000                        
    online2 0.227   1.000                    
    online3 0.132   0.350   1.000                
    online4 0.091   0.177   0.211   1.000            
    online5 0.104   0.067   0.042   0.091   1.000        
    online6 0.053   0.048   0.044   0.033   0.032   1.000    
    online7 -0.098  -0.067  -0.032  -0.016  -0.040  -0.005  1.000
a. Determinant = .753                               
 
Total Variance Explained
Component   Initial Eigenvalues Extraction Sums of Squared Loadings         Rotation Sums of Squared Loadings        
    Total   % of Variance   Cumulative %    Total   % of Variance   Cumulative %    Total   % of Variance   Cumulative %
1   1.679   23.984  23.984  1.679   23.984  23.984  1.527   21.821  21.821
2   1.043   14.899  38.883  1.043   14.899  38.883  1.194   17.063  38.883
3   0.997   14.241  53.124                       
4   0.968   13.832  66.957                       
5   0.882   12.602  79.559                       
6   0.799   11.416  90.975                       
7   0.632   9.025   100.000                      
Extraction Method: Principal Component Analysis.                                     
```
````

Comment: Looking at the correlation matrix I think you need to go back to the drawing board and redesign your questionnaire.

Comment: Hi this is something I can't do and is actually a school assignment. The questionnaire is flawed without a doubt and I understand that. But unfortunately we cannot do anything about it. I would just like to understand why summation of variable would be in the case a better option as oppose to factor analysis.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? More context would help. Summing the variables and doing a factor analysis are completely different things.  

Who told you you should sum them? Your instructor or someone else?  

Btw, you didn't do a factor analysis, you did a Principal Components analysis - see here: [link]https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/the-fundamental-difference-between-principal-component-analysis-and-factor-analysis/)